# Dragging to top to maximize vertically

Tags: gnome, windows, configuration

Am using Ubuntu 18.4 and would like to get this kind of behavior: when I drag a window to the top, it should expand vertically into a half of the display.

**I am using two displays, so it's not about dragging to the left or right side**

Like this:

[image]

Is this possible somehow?

I know *gtile* but I want it to act by mouse dragging, not hotkeys

Comment: No, please update.

Comment: @PRATAP The problem is that it wouldn't work. Or would it? I'd fine with "dragging to top" = "drag to left" but I need to work on the RIGHT display. There is not dragging to the left when the left edge of the right display is effectively just the center

Comment: @Rubi Shnol dragging to the left edge of the right display should maximize it on the left half of the right display. Have you tried it?

Comment: @danzel You can't drag it to the left edge of the right display -- the cursor slides through into the left display

Comment: @Rubi Shnol well, you have to stop the cursor right before the edge.

Comment: @danzel ))) you know how impracticable it is